# Vue Method is executing multiple times

Tags: vue.js

I simply have a method to display the name. Inside that method is a counter incrementing, so that I know how many times the method was called. But upon page load, the method was executed multiple times, 102 times to be exact.

```
<template>
      <div class="row g-2">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div>Enter your name</div>
          <input type="text" v-model="name" /> <br />
          Your name is : {{ outputName() }}
          <div class="border border-danger">Counter : {{ counter }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          name: "",
          counter: 0,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        outputName() {
          this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    
          return this.name;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doing an infinite loop because you're calling a method inside template which updates a property that's also in the template which does multiple rendering and in each rendering it update the property, just print the `name` inside the template, then use an event to update the counter like using a button  :

```
<template>
      <div class="row g-2">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div>Enter your name</div>
          <input type="text" v-model="name" /> <br />
          Your name is : {{ name }}
          <div class="border border-danger" @click="counter++">Counter : {{ counter }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          name: "",
          counter: 0,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        outputName() {
          this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    
        },
      },

    };
    </script>
```